# Send request with @odata.nextLink while it possible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

I have a graph api query to get users. There are 200 users in total. And in each request, I get 25 users and a link (@odata.nextLink) to the next 25.
[image: results 25 users]

[image: query response with @odata.nextLink]

To get all 200 users I want to send query while @odata.nextLink is not equal undefined. And save them to an array in the state.

```
public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient('3')
      .then((client: MSGraphClientV3): void => {
        client
          .api('users')
          .version("v1.0")
          .select("displayName,accountEnabled")
          .expand("manager")
          .top(25)
          .get()
          .then((results) => {
            let usersList: any[] = results.value
            while (results["@odata.nextLink"]) {
              this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
              results = client
                .api(results["@odata.nextLink"])
                .version('v1.0')
                .get()
                .then((results) => {
                  usersList = [...usersList, ...results.value];
                  const users: Array<IUserInfo> = new Array<IUserInfo>();
                  usersList.map((item: any) => {
                    users.push({
                      displayName: item.displayName,
                      accountEnabled: item.accountEnabled,
                      manager: item.manager ? item.manager.displayName : ''
                    });
                  });
                  this.setState({ users: users });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error)
                });
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          });
      })
  }
```

Unfortunately my request is only sent twice, even though @odata.nextLink is still present and I got only 50 users.
Please help, how can I fix ?

Comment: I'm not very good at JS closures and promises, but I would assume that your results which is "results = client.api(results["@odata.nextLink"])" ... are not accessible at upper level where your while condition is checked. most likely you need to return results up with resolve() or something